# Extension of trigonometric functions (like Bessel functions)

Tags: special-functions

This may be more related to math SE, but I got no answer from there, and maybe physics SE can tell me more about practicality of my question.

I learned that the Bessel functions and that family are derived from the ODE
$$
y''+y'/x+(1-\nu^2/x^2)y=0,
$$
and $J_\nu(x)$, $Y_\nu(x)$, $H_\nu^{(1)}(x)$, $H_2^{(2)}(x)$, $I_\nu(x)$, $K_\nu(x)$ have similar properties to $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$, $e^{ix}$, $e^{-ix}$, $\cosh(x)$, $\sinh(x)$. (I'm using the notation in the Arfken's *Mathematical methods for physicists*.)

So I naturally began to wonder if we can also generalize the ODE for trigonometric function $y''+y=0$, to depend on certain index like $\nu$, so we can generate special functions which depend on the index, and which becomes trigonometric function for certain index.  But I'm not sure where should I put the index $\nu$ to make family of functions. If I set, like, $y''+\nu^2y=0$, then solution is just $\sin(\nu x)$, which is basically same as $\sin(x)$. Wait... but maybe we can do this way, $y''+(1-\nu^2/x^2)y=0$?

Is there a extension of trigonometric functions in this(or similar) way? Are they just not practical functions? Or is there a reason that trigonometric functions are special so they should be unique?

Comment: Please don't cross-post unless you really want to get different sites' perspectives on the issue (in which case you should specifically tailor the question to each site you post it in); if you *must* cross-post due to low attention then you should wait one or two days, not a few hours. And finally, if you do cross-post, you should always link to the other versions everywhere you post, or you're just wasting the effort of people who would otherwise not realize that the question has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty I'm sorry I didn't know that.

Comment: No harm no foul ;-). This will likely be closed / migrated, and that's that. There *isn't* an expectation that you will know all the rules and particulars from the get-go, there's only an expectation that you learn them when they're pointed out =).